# read text file containing full path of files copy from source to destination folder recursively (folder wise) using command line batch program

Tags: batch-file, command-line

Read text file containing full path of files copy from source to destination folder recursively (folder wise) list.txt contains full path of various files from root directory to file I tried  xcopy /s source destination its working fine but i `enter code here`want to read files from list and paste in destination folder wise. If my destination folder is

I can read file using command:

```
FOR /F "eol=; tokens=* delims=, " %i in (D:\List.txt) do @echo %i
```

Comment: Using both `tokens=*` and `delims=, ` is pointless. `tokens=*` means there will only be one token, and `delims=, ` means that both the comma and the space are delimiters between tokens. So in this context `delims=, ` is meaningless because if you only have one token, there are no delimiters between tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose that no one can say you didn't post any code.  As for it's relevance... Hmmm...

Ok, your message is pretty unclear. You have incomplete sentences and thoughts, and some seemingly random statements. But I will try to help.

I don't know what you mean by "copy from source to destination folder recursively". Do you mean that you want to copy all the sudirectories in your source to your destination?

You say that you want to copy a list files from the root directory to a destination folder. The actual list of files to copy is contianed in a file called `List.txt` located in the rood of drive D:.

Can I assume that when you say "paste in destination folder wise", that you mean you wish to copy the files into the folder / directory `wise`? Is that correct? What is the path to `wise`?

With the information that you've given, I can help you out a little.

Ok, the idea of having a list of files to copy, plus wanting to copy subdirectories out of the source directory is problematic unless the paths of some of the list of files to copy put them in those subdirectories.  I'm going to assume that is the case.

Since you said the source was the root directory, and `List.txt` is in the root of D:\, I'm going to assume that D:\ is the root that you were speaking of.  You mentioned a folder `wise`, so I'm going to assume that is the destination folder. Also, since you said that `list.txt` contains the entire path of the files to be copied, we can ignore the sorce directory as that is part of the path.

So, making those assumptions, here is your code.

```
@echo off
set dest=d:\wise
set list=d:\list.txt

for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (%list%) do copy %%x %dest%
```

Very short and sweet.

Without sample data and expected outcomes I'm not going to be able to do much better.

You mentioned `XCOPY` but as using xcopy to copy individual files is not really playing to it's strength, I use `copy` instead.

If this is not what you need try to try to be clearer. Speak in whole sentences, and whole ideas. Not sentence fragments and random statements, like your "`enter code here`" statement. I have no idea what that's supposed to  mean.

Comment: Hi James, Let me explain you. I have text file containing list of files(with full path) I want it should be read line by line and  files should be copy as per directory structure at destination folder (recursively) not all files in single directory. I tried with for command in batch file but after reading files gets copied in single folder folder hierarchy not created :( Please reply for further information.